# "have been to some place" vs "be to some place"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, been-vs-gone

There are two phrases:
"have **gone** to" : someone went to some place but **didn't** **come** back.

"have **been** to": someone went to some place and **come** back.

I understand the phrase "have **gone** to" like this: 
1a. I ***went*** to the US.
1b. I ***have gone*** to the US.
With the simple past tense, sentence 1a means the action "went" happened in the past.
With the present perfect tense, sentence 1b means the action "have gone" has finished until now. Therefore, the phrase "have gone to" means someone went to some place but didn't come back.

However I have difficulty in understanding the phrase "have been to".
I made up two sentences 2a and 2b. I am wondering what does the phrase "be to some place" means like in 2a.

2a. I **was to** the US.

2b. I **have been** to the US.

Comment: You would say *I have been **here** before.* but never "I have gone here." Other than a correction of *I was **in** the US.* the meanings do overlap a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> I have gone to the US

*in the context* you are thinking seems weird to me.

**But,** you are right...

> I have been to the US

means you visited the place and came back.

However, `have/has gone to` **not necessarily** mean that s/he will not come back. For instance...

> Where's John? ~ He *has gone* to the supermarket. He'll be ***back*** in an hour.

*has gone...* talks about the 'current status'.

To clarify further...

> He has been to the US - He visited the place at least once. Visited means went and came back
>
> He has gone to the US - He's **in** the US. Of course, he can come back!
>
> He was in the US - This talks about his status of being in the US somewhere in the past. We are not emphasizing on the 'visit' (or else it could have been 'have been to the US').

Let me know any other instance that I missed here.

Answer (score 0):

> Where have you been the last two weeks?
>
> *I was in the US.*

Both responses would work but this one is more natural.

> Have you ever traveled to North America?
>
> *I have been to the US.*

Again both answers would work but this one is much more common.

> Which country were you in when that happened?
>
> *I was in the US.*

The alternative sentence *does not work here*.

> Where are you currently living?
>
> *I have been in the US since...*

The other sentence *doesn't work* here either because the *living/being in* is ongoing.

I hope these examples are helpful even without trying to dive in and explain why the meanings are slightly different and why the tenses don't necessarily match between the question and the answer. Don't try to make too much sense of it. It's probably just something that comes with practice and familiarity.